# How to specify dependencies in Custom CloudFormation resources?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

When creating a Custom CloudFormation Resource implementation, the created resource can later be used to "add" more dependant children onto itself.

For example:

```
ResourceA:
  Type: Custom::Parent

ResourceB:
  Type: Custom::Child
  Properties:
    Parent: !Ref ResourceA
```

Is it sufficient to just add `DependsOn` to `ResourceB` to make sure that it gets removed before `ResourceA` receives the `Delete` request? Like so -

```
ResourceB:
  DependsOn: ResourceA
  Type: Custom::Child
  Properties:
    Parent: !Ref ResourceA
```

Or will there be a case where `ResourceA` receives a `Delete` request and fails, before `ResourceB` finished its process of removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't even need the `DependsOn`. Since you have a reference to A in the properties of B, cloudformation knows that B has a dependency on A, and will only start creating B when A is created.
For deleting, the reverse happens: first B will be removed, then A. 
Cloudformation only deletes resources when no other resource depends on it.